# Set background image to resource image file

Tags: c#

I am trying to set a background image to one from the properties.Resource list. I already know how to retrieve a single image.

I am looping through the images in that list like this:

```
foreach(PropertyInfo property in typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    if (property.Name.Contains("testimage"))
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = (Image)property.Name;
    }
}
```

Now when the form loads it does not display the image. Can someone let me know what i am doing wrong in this situation.

Comment: `(Image)property.GetValue(null, null)`

Comment: @royap this refers to the current form that is having the background changed

Comment: @user3240928 -- I guess I was playing with you.  What I meant is: is it win forms?  WPF?  Other?  You didn't tag your question, so we have no way of knowing really what you're trying to do.  How could we answer why your background image isn't showing if we don't even know what UI technology you're trying to use?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks that worked